# Custom padding for colums in latex

Tags: tables

I am trying to achieve the following:

- MyProjectName %some-space/padding% with PersonName %fill space until right aligned% DurationDates

This is what I have:

```
\newcommand{\headerrownew}[3]
{
    \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{}lXl@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r@{}}
    #1 && #2 & #3%
    \end{tabular*}
}

%arguments : Name of project, duration
\newcommand{\miniprojectinfobullet}[3]
{
    \item
    \headerrownew{\textbf{#1}}{\emph{#2}}{\emph{#3}}%
}
```

But latex says: `Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.`
Can anyone suggest what should be done?

Comment: You can just use `My Project Name:\hspace*{1.0em}Person Name \hfill Duration Date` to achieve what you describe.  You may need `\noindent` at the start. Also, while code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.  This will also go a long way towards clarifying things which are not clear in the description.

Comment: you have used an X column which presumably gave an error (since X columns are not defined for `tabular*` also you are missing many `%` from the ends of lines in your definition. As you have not provided a usable example hard to be more specific

Answer (score 3):

You can add padding via `\hspace*{<length>}` and right align to the line with a `\hfill`

[image]

Alternatively you can use the `tabularx` package as illustrated with `\headerrownewA`, or `tabular*` as illustrated with `\headerrownewB`.

### Notes:

- [The `showframe` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/showframe)
  was used just to show the page margins.
  It is not needed in your actual use case.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{showframe}

\newcommand{\headerrownewA}[3]{%
    \noindent%
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}llXr@{}}
    #1 & #2 && #3
    \end{tabularx}%
}

\newcommand{\headerrownewB}[3]{%
    \noindent
    \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{}ll@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r@{}}
    #1 & #2 & #3
    \end{tabular*}%
}

\begin{document}
\noindent
My Project Name:\hspace*{1.0em}Person Name \hfill Duration Date

\headerrownewA{My Project Name}{Person Name }{Duration Date}
\headerrownewB{My Project Name}{Person Name }{Duration Date}
\end{document}
```